# GMP floating values - print them with given precision in base 10

Tags: c++, output, gmp, number-formatting

Let's say I have a

```
mpf_t number;
```

that equals 1.25. I want to print it with a given precision, even if there would be trailing zero's, for example

```
1.2500000
```

When I try to print it by using a mpf_get_str function, it prints in scientific (e) format,

```
mpf_out_str(stdout,10,7,number); //prints 0.125e1
```

When I use c++'s cout, as mpf_t has << overloaded,

```
cout << number << endl; //prints 1.25
```

and when I try to print it by calling setprecision(given precision) in cout, i still get 1.25

```
cout << setprecision(7) << number << endl; //prints 1.25
```

So, how can I print the number as I'd like it?

Comment: Since you are using C++, isn't `mpf_class` more appropriate than `mpf_t`?

Comment: In C, gmp_printf has suitable options. In C++, DomCote already answered.

Answer (score 2):

You need to send std::fixed to std::cout.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gmpxx.h>

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
  mpf_t mpft;

  mpf_init(mpft);
  mpf_set_d(mpft,1.25);

  std::cout.precision(7);
  std::cout << std::fixed;
  std::cout << mpft << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```